# Awkward Showcase only showing half image in IE?

Tags: jquery, slider, slideshow

I am using the Awkward showcase slider and it seems to only show half an image when the page is loaded then after a few seconds continues to slide...does anyone know the issue for this??

Answer (score 0):

found the answer - dont have align centre above the code!